# vector of a template class with unknown parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a program that has to use `std::vector`, while the types of elements are unknown. The `std::vector` can hold different types of elements. Specifically, these types are enumerated from a template class. What I want to do is something like below,

```
#include <vector>

template <size_t N>
class Element{
  int array[N];
};

int main(){
  std::vector<Element> vec;
  // do something
}
```

where, class `Element` is the types of objects to be stored in the vector. It holds an array of an arbitrary size. The vector stores some `Elements` objects with unknown paremter `N`.

One solution I found is something like below, since the values of `N` are known at compilation time.

```
std::vector<std::variant<Element<1>, Element<2>, Element<3> > vec;
```

But it would be tricky as I have to enumerate all of them, and the application changes a lot.

I know this simple example can be resolved through dynamic memory allocation, but this is just an example, the program is much more complex.

Is there a better solution for this?

Comment: [std::vector<std::any>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)?

Comment: You need to use something like variant; there's simply no other option, since `std::vector` stores elements in an array and `Element` has a different size depending on the template parameter. Note that the result may be very memory inefficient, when using variant though because of the differences in size of the elements. Furthermore unless you do store the type (which variant does), you won't be able to use the vector lacking the knowlege about the number of elements for each element.

Comment: Please define "better".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could suggest two approaches for this.

### Ditching Templates

You could ditch the template parameter in your `Element` class and have it contain a `std::vector` whose size is set upon construction and never changed. Something like this:

```
class Element {
public:
    Element(std::size_t size) : m_vector(size) {};

private:
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
};
```

And then you use the `m_vector` just as if it was an array. No problems in your `main()` here.

### Using Inheritance and Polymorphism

I think you refer to this when you talk about dynamic allocation, but I'll include it anyways. If you want to use templates, you can have your class `Element` inherit from a non-templated abstract class to have an interface of all the methods. For example:

```
class ElementBase {
public:
    ElementBase() = default;
    virtual ~ElementBase() = default;
    
    virtual std::size_t arraySize() const = 0;
    virtual const int *array() const = 0;
};


template<std::size_t N>
class Element : public ElementBase {
public:
    Element() = default;
    ~Element() override = default;
    
    std::size_t arraySize() const override {
        return N;
    }
    
    const int *array() const override {
        return m_array;
    } 

private:
    int m_array[N];
};
```

With this approach you cannot have a `std::vector<ElementBase>` in your `main()` because the class is abstract, but you can have a `std::vector<ElementBase*>` or something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ElementBase>>` if you are going to need dynamic allocation.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is obsolete since C++ 11. Use `std::unique_ptr` instead.